# Dynamic rest call using lifecycle methods

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJS version 13.4.13.

I need to perform a rest call where the rest path needs to be determined by the value from the
selection of a dropdown.

Thus I end up doing the following inside a component within components folder instead of

doing the rest call via app/page.js as a server component rest call.

```
// market is the value selected from drop down. Market is a state value provided via zustand.
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => { await myRestCall(market) })();
}, []);
```

This does work.

This is so that I can present data from the rest call at the main page itself on https://example.com.

I don't want to show it like https://example.com/market.

Is this a good idea, is there a way I could do this using server component?

Just feels wrong using `useEffect` for this. Like I might as well just have a react project.

I am not using the capabilities of server component rest calls. Pls advice.

Comment: ...why is market not in the useEffect dependency array? Don't you want it to re-run when the user selects a different value? "Is there a way I could do this using server component?" How could you possibly do that *before* the user picks something from the dropdown? "Just feels wrong using useEffect for this" why? The whole point of React is that it *reacts* to state changes like user input.

Comment: @JaredSmith Good point on the dependency. Will add it. Guess just me thinking to avoid the use of useEffect if possible. Sounds like I can't in this instance.

Comment: Nah, not in this case. Even if you can fetch the data server-side though it depends a lot. We did some studies at work and found contrary to conventional wisdom that we had much better conversions by having the client fetch data rather than doing the service calls on the server before serving the page, even though there's nothing useful on the page until the data from those calls come in. Always measure!